# C# Unit Testing Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

The method in question is:

```
 public SqlDA(string ConnectionString)
    {
        this._CurrentConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        this._CurrentConnection.Open();
    }
```

The unit test I have is:

```
[TextFixture]
public class BasicTest
{
   public string connstring;
   public SqlDA da;

   [SetUp]
   public void SetUp()
   {
      connstring="Server=localhost;Database=db;user_id=user;password=password;Connect Timeout=1000";
      da = new SqlDA(connstring);
   }

   [Test]
   public void Test
   {
   string result = da.Method();
   Assert.AreEqual(0,result);
   }
}
```

It throws the error in the setup. I have been trying to figure out what is causing the issue for a while with no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The member variable da is declared as a SqlDA type and in SetUp() you try to assign a type of DA to it.

If the type DA does not derive from SqlDA then the member variable da will be null.  You then try to call Method on da which won't work, because it is null.

Comment: Oh, oops. I typo'd when I was copying from my code. It should be da = new SqlDA(connstring).